# stop meta_search doing sql to early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

in the [docs](http://rdoc.info/github/ernie/meta_search/master/MetaSearch/Searches/ActiveRecord/ClassMethods#metasearch-instance_method) it's said:

```
MyObject.search()
```

returns an instance of MetaSearch::Builder (something like ActiveRecord::Relation). But in my case when I do this I get a collection of objects because the sql-query is send to the database.

I would like to have something like this:

```
search = MyObject.search() # no sql-query should be done here

count = search.count # count sql done

objects = search.all # select sql done - maybee with pagination
```

does anyone know how to stop Meta_search from doing the the query to early?

-> ok, something mysterious going on in my shell:

```
search = MyObject.search() # queries the database
search = MyObject.search(); 0 # stores a MetaSearch-Object in search
```

the console seems to call an extra method after each comand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing in irb, be aware that returned objects are inspected. In the case of a MetaSearch builder, this means the relation gets inspected. If you have a look at ActiveRecord's inspect method, in relation.rb, you'll see that it calls to_a, which executes the query and returns the results.